# UTF-8 is not working with Cyrillic alphabet in Pycharm

Tags: python, windows, encoding, utf-8, pycharm

It works okay if I'm doing something within a program, but it doesn't work when I'm reading a file.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:

    print(f.read())
```

Input (text.txt):

```
слово
строка
```

Output:

```
СЃР»РѕРІРѕ
СЃС‚СЂРѕРєР°
```

I set both global and project encoding to UTF-8. No result.

Comment: What's the encoding of the `text.txt` file?  If that's something other than UTF-8, that could be your trouble.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi UTF-8 is not necessarily the default.  `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is the default.  From the output, I'd say the default was `cp1251`, but the file is encoded in `utf8`.

Answer (score 1):

The file is encoded in UTF-8, but your locale default is `cp1251`.  Be explicit and always open a file with its known encoding:

```
#!python3
with open('test.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Python 2 users need to use the `io` module.  The built-in `open` of Python 2 doesn't support the `encoding` parameter.  `io.open` is Python 3's implementation and is available in Python 2 and Python 3 for portability.

This code is compatible with both Python 2 and 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function # for Python 3 print syntax in Python 2.
import io
with io.open('test.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Ref: [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)